# Problema con cookies en copia de Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, migration

Estoy haciendo una copia de un sitio WordPress desde un hosting a local, hago los pasos cómo siempre:

- Descargar base de datos
- Descargar archivos
- Cambiar datos en `wp-config.php`
- Cambiar dirección del sitio en `wp-options` en la base de datos

Pero a la hora de entrar a `wp-admin` me aparece este error

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mi-sitio/wp-config.php:1) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mi-sitio/wp-login.php on line 424`

Y sobre los campos de login me aparece esta alerta:

> ERROR: Las cookies se han bloqueado debido a un resultado no esperado. Para obtener ayuda, por favor mira esta documentación o inténtalo en los foros de soporte.

Ya he leido que puede ser un problema con un espacio en la estiquetas `<?php` pero no es mi caso. Ya eliminé las cookies y tampoco.

Adicionalmente el sitio tiene instalado WP-SuperCache y Wordfence, creo que estos son los que están causando los problemas, ya los desactivé e incluso eliminé las tablas de estos plugins pero no ha funcionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema estaba en el plugin WP Super Cache, para resolver el problema, deshabilité el plugin y creé un nuevo archivo `wp-config` para quitar todo lo que no estaba por defecto, actualicé los datos de la base de datos y todo quedó funcionando bien, luego desinstalé el plugin.